# Interpretation of numpy polyfit on a big dataset

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I'm analyzing a publicly available dataset: an assessment of properties in San Francisco for tax purposes (https://data.sfgov.org/Housing-and-Buildings/Historic-Secured-Property-Tax-Rolls/wv5m-vpq2). It can be downloaded as a [CSV file](https://data.sfgov.org/api/views/wv5m-vpq2/rows.csv?accessType=DOWNLOAD), which assumes the filename 'Historic_Secured_Property_Tax_Rolls.csv'.

Using this file, I'm trying to figure out the annual growth rate of the Land Values, excluding zero values. The dataset is so large that I get errors if I try to plot it, so I'm firstly trying to rely on my understanding of how `polyfit` works.

I've used the following code to derive a linear fit of the natural logarithm of the 'Land Value' column plotted against the 'Fiscal Year' column:

```
import pandas as pd

# Read in data downloaded from https://data.sfgov.org/api/views/wv5m-vpq2/rows.csv?accessType=DOWNLOAD
df = pd.read_csv('Historic_Secured_Property_Tax_Rolls.csv')

df_nz = df[df['Closed Roll Assessed Land Value'] > 0]   # Only consider non-zero Land Values

p = np.polyfit(df_nz['Closed Roll Fiscal Year'], np.log(df_nz['Closed Roll Assessed Land Value']), 1)
```

This yields the following values for `p`:

```
In [42]: p
Out[42]: array([  4.18802559e-02,  -7.23804441e+01])
```

As I understand it, the slope of the linear fit should be represented by `p[1]`. However, this would represent an implausible growth rate of -724% per year. If it were `p[0]`, however, it would be a more plausible 4.2% per year.

I'm wondering if I haven't somehow misinterpreted the result, and whether the growth rate is somehow represented by `p[0]` instead of `p[1]`?

Comment: The Data Incubator much? ;)

Comment: "For the challenge questions, please: 1. Answer the questions yourself without asking others for assistance."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Returns
-------
p : ndarray, shape (M,) or (M, K)
    Polynomial coefficients, highest power first.  If `y` was 2-D, the
    coefficients for `k`-th data set are in ``p[:,k]``.
```

This tells me that the `4.2%` is the coefficient on the log term.

My first reaction would be to look at the growth rates of the mean, median, etc.

```
columns = ['Closed Roll Fiscal Year', 'Closed Roll Assessed Land Value']
df_ = df[columns].copy()
df_.columns = ['Year', 'Value']
df_ = df_[df_.iloc[:, 1] > 0]
df_['log_value'] = np.log(df_.Value)

df_desc = df_.groupby('Year').log_value.describe()

desc_cols = ['mean', '25%', '50%', '75%']

df_desc.unstack()[desc_cols].plot()
```

[image]

Just a thought.

Comment: Thanks piRSquared, I must have misread the documentation at http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html the first time.